# Error Update and Add data in Laravel MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

Want to ask earlier, I did insert add data in the `attendance_details` table, it worked, but I want the `attendance` table to be automatically changed to the Done table to `1` before `0` before submitting. But the error at signup says something like this `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.` Here is my MySQL table:

Table attendance_details:
[image: Screenshot Table attendance_details in MySQL]

and table attendance:
[image: Screenshot Table attendance]

in the attendance table there is a `Done` table still `0` after submitting it should be changed to `1`

Code:

**Blade**

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('add.data')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="id_atte" value="{{ $dataAttendance->id_atte }}"
>
```

**Controller**

```
public function ViewData($id){
        $dataAttendance = Attendance::findOrFail($id);
        
        $dataAttendanceTa = Attendance::join('subjects', 'attendances.id_subject', '=', 'subjects.id_sub')
            ->join('class_infos', 'subjects.id_class', '=', 'class_infos.id')
            ->join('class_details', 'class_infos.id', '=', 'class_details.id_class')
            ->join('users', 'class_details.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('attendances.id_atte', '=', $id)
            ->get();

        return view('index', compact('dataAttendanceDe', 'dataAttendance', 'dataAttendanceTa'));
    }




public function AddData(Request $request) {
        // Add Data attendance_details
        foreach($request->get('id_atte') as $index => $value) {
            AttendanceDetail::create([
                'id_atte' => $value,
                'id_student' => $request->get('id_student')[$index],
                'id_atte_type' =>$request->get('id_atte_type')[$index],
                'note' => $request->get('note')[$index]
            ]);
        }

        // Update Data attendance
        $data = Attendance::find($request->id_atte);
        $data->done = '0';
        $data->save();

        return redirect('teacher/data-attendance');
    }
```

Where is the coding wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context of your code `$request->id_atte` returns an array of id's which you loop over. This means that `$data = Attendance::find($request->id_atte);` will return an array of models instead of just one, which means it cannot be saved.

You could either set the `done` attribute in another foreach loop or within the origional creation.

Answer (score 0):

inside the loop function, you should update the Attendance model

```php
    public function AddData(Request $request) 
    {
            // Add Data attendance_details
            foreach($request->get('id_atte') as $index => $value) {
                AttendanceDetail::create([
                    'id_atte' => $value,
                    'id_student' => $request->get('id_student')[$index],
                    'id_atte_type' =>$request->get('id_atte_type')[$index],
                    'note' => $request->get('note')[$index]
                ]);
               // Update Data attendance
               $data = Attendance::find($value);
               $data->done = '0';
               $data->save();
            }
    
            return redirect('teacher/data-attendance');
        }
```

OR you can use the update query method after **whereIn**

```php
    
    // Update Data attendance
    $data = Attendance::whereIn('id', $request->id_atte)->update([
        'done' => '0'
    ]);
```